# Nativescript don't send header correctly using angular service

Tags: android, angular, api, httprequest, nativescript

When i send a normal get request to my deployed nodejs webserver it tell me there is no cookies sent in the header while i ve already write it in the headers of my api service

my service

```
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private global: Global) { }
  verifAuth() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.get(`${this.global.url}verif`, this.global.header)
        .toPromise()
        .then(res => { resolve(res); })
        .catch(err => { reject(err); console.log('err', err) });
    });
```

my declared default header

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class Global {
    url: String; header;
    constructor() {
        this.url = "https://fmm.etudiant.xyz/";
        this.header = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'cookies': `xt=${appSetting.getString('xt')}`,
            }),
            withCredentials: true
        };
    }
}
```

and when i debug the request i found this

[request header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5qXk.png)

i expect that the token must be parsed and get the result of user but the backend server tell that there is no cookies while it work fine with an other website

Answer (score 0):

Sending Cookie in Http request is not yet supported, there is a [open feature request at Github](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2424).

Comment: i am not sending my real cookie, i just create new variable called cookies and save  my token into it (xt=).., when i access it with req.headers.cookies, i found it but i can't access it req.cookies as i do in the web version